# append new records with already loaded record on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using getjson to show records on page. Basically i want to show only new added record with already loaded records on webpage. I used set interval option and its working fine the issue is when set interval call it append all records it shows duplication. please let me know how can i handle this duplication.

```
 function updates() {
var url="http://192.168.0.102/newsget.php";

$.getJSON(url,function(json){


// loop through the members here
$.each(json.members,function(i,dat){
$("body").append(

'<div data-role="page" id="'+dat.pagename+'" data-title="'+dat.pagename+'">'+
        '<div data-role="header">'+
            '<h1>'+dat.post_title+'</h1>'+
            '<a data-role="button" href="#news" data-transition="flip" data-icon="arrow-l" data-corners="false">Back</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div data-role="content">'+

            '<img src="http://192.168.0.102/uploads/'+dat.imageurl+'" alt="'+dat.post_title+'" />'+

            '<p>'+dat.description+'</p>'+

        '</div>'+
        '<div data-role="footer">'+
            '<h2>Copyrights All rights Reserved by ABC</h2>'+
            '<p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2015</p>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'




    );
   setTimeout(updates, 2000);

   });




   $.each(json.members,function(i,dat){
   $("#grid").append(

   '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="portfolio-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c ui-corner-none"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt">'+
                    '<div class="ui-btn-text">'+
                        '<a href="#'+dat.pagename+'" class="ui-link-inherit ui-corner-none">'+
                            '<img src="http://192.168.0.102/uploads/'+dat.imageurl+'" class="ui-li-thumb ui-corner-none">'+
                            '<h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+dat.post_title+'</h3>'+
                            '<p class="ui-li-desc">'+dat.post_content+'</p>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<a href="#portfolio1" title="Purchase album" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c">'+
     '<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">'+
     '</span>'+
     '<span data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></span></span></a>'+



                '</li>'




        );


       });


       })
      .done(function() {
      //alert( "second success" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
      alert( "Check your net connection or server is down due to some maintence" );
      });

      }

     });
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have no model. It appears like you are checking for data every n seconds and you want to update your view with the new data. Do you feel comfortable with creating a model, and using that as the context for what is in your view?

Comment: Basically, in summary, create a variable for your model (looks like an array). then your callback from the getJSON function should point to a function that updates the model. then after updating the model, you can render your content again. (separate the code to render your view, and only worry about rendering the model data) I would personally use handlebars or some JST instead of the string concatenation.

Comment: Hi Charlie, First I would like to thank you for this code. Basically i am creating jquery mobile application. In my app has "news" section i am adding news from the php based admin panel every thing works fine except the only issue when the user has already open that news page and at that time I am added one more news so I want to show that news automatically with out the page refresh on user mobile device. I hope you understand, so if you have any good thing or suggestion or code please share with me. if you need more clarification please let me know. i will also use your code

Comment: Yep, I get it. Honestly I would use a web socket for that. You can look into that when you have time. Anyway, what you are trying to do is called long polling, my answer will work fine for that, as it will only add new records to the page. You just need to use Ajax and poll your server (your setTimeout) and then send the response to the Model.getNewData

Comment: Charlie i need your help also, can you tell me how can i protect my .apk file or how can i hide or encrypt javascript code on page. i am using cordova

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the pre-loaded divs have assigned ids like the newly generated ones, before the $("body").append part you could put an if condition in order to check if the current div is already existing. Something like this:

```
function updates() {
  var url="http://192.168.0.102/newsget.php";

  $.getJSON(url,function(json){

  // loop through the members here
  $.each(json.members,function(i,dat){
    if ($("#"+dat.pagename).length === 0) { // New if condition!
      $("body").append(...
```

A bit quick 'n dirty but I hope it helps.

PS: I suggest you to properly indent your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
// My Model
var Model = {

    url: 'your/url/here.php',

    content: [{
        id: 9087,
        foo: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 9088,
        foo: 'foo'
    }],

    getNewData: function () {
        $.getJSON(this.url, this.addNewRecords);
    },

    addNewRecords: function (arr) {
        // important to distinguish JSON from JSOL
        var i = 0;

        for (i; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            if (!this.keyValueInModel('id', arr[i].id)) {
                Model.content.push(arr[i]);  // push the record into your model
                myView.render([arr[i]]); // render the record to the view
            }
        }

    },

    keyValueInModel: function (key, val) {
        var i = 0,
            result = false,
            arr = Model.content;

        for (i; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            if (arr[i][key] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};


// My View
var myView = {

    context: null, // +1 if you figure out why you should context your view to a specific node, and actually do it. I figure I will leave you some room to learn....



    render: function (records) {

        var i = 0,
            dat;

        for (i; i < records.length; i += 1) {
            dat = records[i];

            $("body").append(

                '<div data-role="page" id="' + dat.pagename + '" data-title="' + dat.pagename + '">' +
                '<div data-role="header">' +
                '<h1>' + dat.post_title + '</h1>' +
                '<a data-role="button" href="#news" data-transition="flip" data-icon="arrow-l" data-corners="false">Back</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div data-role="content">' +

                '<img src="http://192.168.0.102/uploads/' + dat.imageurl + '" alt="' + dat.post_title + '" />' +

                '<p>' + dat.description + '</p>' +

                '</div>' +
                '<div data-role="footer">' +
                '<h2>Copyrights All rights Reserved by ABC</h2>' +
                '<p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2015</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>');

        }

        $("#grid").append(

            '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="portfolio-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c ui-corner-none"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt">' +
            '<div class="ui-btn-text">' +
            '<a href="#' + dat.pagename + '" class="ui-link-inherit ui-corner-none">' +
            '<img src="http://192.168.0.102/uploads/' + dat.imageurl + '" class="ui-li-thumb ui-corner-none">' +
            '<h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + dat.post_title + '</h3>' +
            '<p class="ui-li-desc">' + dat.post_content + '</p>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<a href="#portfolio1" title="Purchase album" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c">' +
            '<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">' +
            '</span>' +
            '<span data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></span></span></a>' +



            '</li>'




        );
    }
};

setTimeout(Model.getNewData, 2000);
```